# What determines if a shockwave is normal or oblique

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

So I am studying Gas dynamics and I know the math regarding Normal and Oblique shockwaves, but I am not sure why would one occur and not the other. Is there a rule when normal shocks will occur or when oblique?

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: How would this relate: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/34943/10902 ?

Comment: @SolarMike this is another question of mine which I still dont have an answer to. but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Check out how the shockwave hits the surface.

Answer (score 0):

When a supersonic flow is turned towards itself,i.e., the supersonic flow is forced to change its flow direction, this generates oblique shock waves. If it is not so, then normal shock wave would be generated.